# How do I add a primary key to a huge table without a primary key

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, alter-table

I have a huge table (millions of records) that keeps history of *event*s.

Table is automatically populated, with newer records added all the time. The field timestamp refers to when a row was added. Records are never UPDATEd.

The most common queries (all too slow!):

- latest record for a given `ip`
- latest record for a given `mac`
- latest 100 records for a given `ip`
- latest 100 records for a given `mac`
- all records for a given IP within the last X days

Here's the table description:

```
  Column   |            Type             | Nullable | Default
-----------+-----------------------------+----------+--------
 event     | text                        | not null |
 ip        | inet                        | not null |
 mac       | macaddr8                    | not null |
 timestamp | timestamp without time zone | not null | now()
Indexes:
    "ip_idx" btree (ip)
    "mac_idx" btree (mac)
    "time_idx" btree ("timestamp")
    "timestamp_ip_event_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree ("timestamp", ip, event)
```

I'm thinking about adding a primary key `row_id` with auto-increment.

Hopefully, that would speed up the queries where the actual value of `timestamp` doesn't really matter.

Also, it will make the table easier to use with Django, which prefers tables to have numeric primary key.

The script that populates the table relies on the column order, so the new column `row_id` should be at the end.

For existing rows, `row_id` should be in the order of ascending timestamp.

This last requirement is puzzling me -- how do I write the ALTER TABLE to ensure that the order of existing records by `row_id` will be the same as with `timestamp`?

Comment: There's no "order of existing records" in a table; rows are ordered by a query if ORDER BY is specified. And why do you expect your proposed surrogate primary key to improve performance of queries based on time? Have you tried indexes on `timestamp, ip` and `timestamp, mac`?

Comment: The purpose of a Primary Key is for data integrity, not performance. Indexes improve performance, and the data type of the key field of those indexes are negligible when it comes to for performance. Millions of rows is not that much, so if your queries are having performance problems, it's likely an index or query tuning problem. Without seeing the example slow queries and their `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`s, there's not much else that can be advised specifically.

Comment: You don't need `"time_idx"` index because you already have `"timestamp"` field as first in `"timestamp_ip_event_key"`

Comment: @mustaccio by "order of existing records" I meant I was comparing the ordering by newly added primary key vs ordering by timestamp

Comment: @J.D. it's not *just* performance. There are other benefits of adding a primary key.

Comment: Why would ordering by a surrogate key be preferable to ordering by the timestamp (even if they result in the same order)?

Comment: @mustaccio There are multiple reasons to have a surrogate primary key. My question is how to add it to ensure proper ordering of existing rows

Comment: Well, surely `alter table` is _not_ the method of setting those values for existing rows. Perhaps you could rephrase your question to make clearer what exactly you want help with.

Comment: @GrannyAching "*it's not just performance. There are other benefits of adding a primary key.*" - Sure, which my previous comment already mentioned. But when you say "*Hopefully, that would speed up the queries*" it sounds like you're trying to fix a performance problem, which adding a primary key won't really solve for you. I see based on jjanes's comments, I'm not the only one who interpreted your Post this way.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to think an artificial primary key will speed up those queries.  What really need are indexes on `(ip, timestamp)` and `(mac, timestamp)`.

Comment: There are other benefits to having a primary key.

Comment: Sure. I was responding to your post which mentioned these performance issues, not to something else you could have posted but didn't.